# Building a Red Black tree using a structure as a node

Tags: c++, beginner, classes, tree

I have the following structure:

```
struct Keys
{
   //value of word in the vector<string> words.
   string word;
   //index of word in the vector<string> words.
   int index;
  //I want to compare the element **word** of the structure, this is why i overloaded the operators
    //After Editing
   bool operator>(const Keys& rhs) const { return  word > rhs.word; }
   bool operator==(const Keys& rhs) const { return word == rhs.word; }

};
```

I want to insert this structure into a Red Black tree, then I want to search for a given word and print its index.

```
int main()
{
    kreb = new RedBlackTree<Keys>();
    vector<string> words;
    words.push_back("hello");
    words.push_back("how");
    words.push_back("are");
    words.push_back("you");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        kreb->InsertNode({words[i],i});
    }

    string w = "hello";
    //if word is found
    if(kreb->AccessNode({w,0}) != 0)
    {
      cout << kreb->AccessNode({w,0})->GetValue().index << endl;
    }
}
```

Instead of inserting integers into the red black tree, I want to insert a structure.
In the structure, I've overloaded the operators `>` and `==` to be able to compare the structure objects in the red black tree (or whatever it is called).

What do you think?  I am  new to C++ and I want to be sure that I am doing it correctly.

**Red-Black Tree Code:**

```
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <windows.h> //for coloring output only

using namespace std;

template <class T> class RBNode
{
private:
    bool isRed;
    T value;
    RBNode<T> *left, *right, *parent;
public:
    //Node()
    //{
    //  left = NULL;
    //  right = NULL;
    //}
    RBNode(T value)
    {
        this->isRed = true;
        this->value = value;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        parent = NULL;
    }
    void Recolor()
    {
        if (this->isRed) this->isRed = false;
        else this->isRed = true;
    }
    bool IsRed()
    {
        return isRed;
    }
    T GetValue()
    {
        return this->value;
    }
    RBNode* GetLeft()
    {
        return this->left;
    }
    RBNode* GetRight()
    {
        return this->right;
    }
    RBNode* GetParent()
    {
        return this->parent;
    }
    void ClearParent()
    {
        this->parent = NULL;
    }
    void SetLeft(RBNode* left)
    {
        this->left = left;
        if(left != NULL) left->parent = this;
    }
    void SetRight(RBNode* right)
    {
        this->right = right;
        if(right != NULL) right->parent = this;
    }
};

template <class T> class RedBlackTree
{
private:
    RBNode<T>* root;

    //the three basic functionalities (inner implementation)
    RBNode<T>* AccessNode(RBNode<T> *root, T value)
    {
        if(root->GetValue() == value)
        {
            return root;
        }
        else if(root->GetValue() > value)
        {
            if(root->GetLeft() == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                return this->AccessNode(root->GetLeft(), value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(root->GetRight() == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                return this->AccessNode(root->GetRight(), value);
            }
        }
    }
    void InsertNode(RBNode<T> *root, T value)
    {
        //regular BST insert
        RBNode<T>* insertedNode = NULL;
        if(root->GetValue() == value)
        {
            //skip
        }
        else if(root->GetValue() > value)
        {
            if(root->GetLeft() == NULL)
            {
                insertedNode = new RBNode<T>(value);
                root->SetLeft(insertedNode);
            }
            else
            {
                this->InsertNode(root->GetLeft(), value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(root->GetRight() == NULL)
            {
                insertedNode = new RBNode<T>(value);
                root->SetRight(insertedNode);
            }
            else
            {
                this->InsertNode(root->GetRight(), value);
            }
        }
        //restore uniform black height
        if (insertedNode == NULL) return;
        this->SolveDoubleRedProblem(root);
        insertedNode = NULL;
    }

public:
    RedBlackTree()
    {
        this->root = NULL;
    }
    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return root == NULL;
    }

    //the three basic functionalities (clients interface)
    RBNode<T>* AccessNode(T value)
    {
        if (this->IsEmpty()) return NULL;
        else return this->AccessNode(root, value);
    }
    void InsertNode(T value)
    {
        if (this->IsEmpty())
        {
            this->root = new RBNode<T>(value);
            this->root->Recolor();
        }
        else this->InsertNode(this->root, value);
    }

};
```

Comment: I'm getting an auto-flag saying that this is excessively long.  You could probably split the red-black code into different parts, or just leave out some portion of it.  Just keep whatever you absolutely need reviewed.

Comment: ok @Jamal. All what I need from the Three is the Insert and AccessNode Functions.

Comment: Is the **bool operator>(const Keys& rhs){ return  rhs.word < word; }** in the Key structure correct?

Comment: ok no problem. See @Jamal what i am doing is inserting Objects into the tree instead for example of integers and strings only. and I am comparing the objects by using Word.

Comment: the Tree class is not important. I am sure that it's right. I just need to know if the Operators > and == are right. And If can use another structure

Comment: Yes, those should work, though I think `operator>` should be `word > rhs.word` or `!(word < rhs.word)`.  They should also both be `const`.

Comment: I see i'll edit the text.np

Comment: The `const` in both overloads would look like this: `bool operator==(const Keys& rhs) const { return word == rhs.word; }`

Comment: @Jamal one more question in the part 
**if(kreb->AccessNode({w,0}) != 0)** Can I use NULL instead of 0 **if(kreb->AccessNode({w,NULL}) != 0)** When I am doing the comparison I just Just the first parameter **w**

Comment: Yes, just use `NULL` when dealing with pointers and such (not numerical values).  Or, if you have C++11, use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `operator>` and `operator==` are correct, but you should also define their complements.  Users may also expect an `operator<` and an `operator!=`:

  ```
  bool operator<(const Keys& rhs) const { return word < rhs.word; }
  ```

  ```
  bool operator!=(const Keys& rhs) const { return !(word == rhs.word); }
  ```
- [Prefer `std::size_type` over `size_t` for the vector's loop counter type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276053/1950231):

  ```
  // template type depending on specific vector type
  std::vector<std::string>::size_type;
  ```

  This will allow you to access the entire vector, regardless of its size.  `std::size_type` is also portable as it is defined as part of each STL container.
- Prefer [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) to `NULL` if using C++11.
- Member functions that don't modify data members should be `const`.  This would include the "getters" and those that return `bool`.
- The `this->` is not needed everywhere as the current object is already in scope.  However, you will need it if a parameter shares the same name as a data member (commonly found in a constructor).  Then, you'll need the `this->` to refer to the data member.
- `RBNode()` and `RedBlackTree()`:

  ```
  RBNode(T value)
  {
      this->isRed = true;
      this->value = value;
      left = NULL;
      right = NULL;
      parent = NULL;
  }
  ```

  ```
  RedBlackTree()
  {
      this->root = NULL;
  }
  ```

  should be [initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists):

  ```
  // could still be written vertically
  //   to make list easier to maintain
  RBNode(T value)
      : isRed(true)
      , value(value)
      , left(NULL)
      , right(NULL)
      , parent(NULL)
  {}
  ```

  ```
  RedBlackTree() : root(NULL) {}
  ```
- You have this in `main()`:

  ```
  kreb = new RedBlackTree<Keys>();
  ```

  ...but no `delete` anywhere!  Whenever you use `new`, you *must* use `delete` appropriately, otherwise you'll cause a memory leak.  [C++ doesn't have a garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147130/why-doesnt-c-have-a-garbage-collector).

Comment: C++ **Fortunately** dies not have a garbage collector. It has fine grain deterministic garbage collection that guarantees that object destructors are called correctly. Garbage collected languages have problems guaranteeing object destruction and even when the destructor is called it does not mean the object is dead see [Java Resurrection](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/java-object-resurrection.html) and see [C# implementing disposable the Garbage collector suppression and multiple destroys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You already use `std::vector` in your example, so then why don't you use `std::map`?  All known `std::map` implementations are red-black tree based.

Example:

```
typedef map<string, int> RedBlackTree;
RedBlackTree myStorage;

for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    myStorage.emplace(words[i], i);

string w = "hello";
auto itr = myStorage.find(w);
if (itr != mtStorade.cend())
    cout << itr->second << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestion is great. I am actually using `multimap` which allows duplicates. `map` won't allow it.